# is it possible to display vim spellcheck options in the quick fix window?

Tags: vim, spell-check

I am currently midway through a simple vim spell check plugin.
i have had difficulty finding help on how i can display the options for corrections in the quick fix window.

Is it possible vim spellcheck options `z=` can be displayed there?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for, specifically, is not possible. However, you may emulate the behavior you're looking for by opening your own window with a scratch buffer, then filling it with the output of `spellsuggest()`.

You will also need to create a number of buffer local mappings to handle user interaction.

See:

```
:help special-buffers
:help map-local
:help spellsuggest()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been maintaining this spell checker plugin for vim more than a decade ago: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=135

It still has a few features that have never been integrated in vim.

- It does not explicitly use the quickfix window, but a scratch buffer.
- Replacements often selected get a higher score next time suggestions are requested
- It uses aspell or ispell for the spell checking.